# CMS page is not displaying content and title

Tags: magento-1.7

I created CMS page, but when I view it on frontend - no content is displayed. And instead of showing CMS page title, it shows default Magento title (for code `echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();`).

- I'm 100% sure that I'm on this page and URL is correct. And if I change CMS page "template" - the new template appears, just no content and incorrect title.
- I tried clearing cache and reindexing.

What this might be? Please recommend what's the best way to debug this problem?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Perhaps you could eliminate everything in the content area (save for a word or two) as a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, it was a typo in cms.xml file.